# Apport is broken

Tags: apt

```
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
apport
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have already tried removing apport but it still shows the same error after installation of any package....Please help

So I tried reinstalling...It showed again some errors...

```
sudo apt install apport --reinstall
[sudo] password for abhijeet: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  apport-gtk | apport-kde
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/120 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 239978 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5_all.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried 'apt install apport --reinstall' ?

Comment: @SorenA Edited it...see above...I tried reinstall now...

Comment: Have you, by any chance, updated or installed a new version of python recently ?

Comment: What's the output of `which python` and `python --version`? What's your Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to install dropbox on Ubuntu 16.04. For me the following worked:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

-> change to python2.7 instead of 3.5

```
sudo apt install apport --reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same  problem, again I believe caused when I had a problem with my DropBox installation and updates to my Python installation. (With no legacy requirements, I'd only installed Python3). Realised my problems were to do with lack of Python2 on my system, but struggled until I found the answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt